# Menubar for Messages in Yosemite

Tags: macos, messages

Did Yosemite eliminate the Menubar icon for Messages? I don't see any preference to turn it back on. I found an Apple KB article that seems like it would offer the answer, but always results in a blank page.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH15045

The irony is that I always previously disabled it, but the continuity features in iOS 8 and Yosemite have made Messages appealing to me for the very first time.

Thanks.

Update: Thanks to @Tetsujin I was able to see the KB article, but apparently something is different about my preferences since I don't see the option described.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean Yosemite? Because Continuity was introduced in OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Oh geez, I really did. Man is that embarrassing. Thanks.

Comment: btw, if you mean the kb article never resolves, it seems quite commong. Workaround is to clear the URL back to just http://support.apple.com/kb/ or alternatively http://www.apple.com/support/ [they will often auto-resolve to your own country] then add the KB id into the search, top right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable Bonjour or AOL IM or another service to get that option to pop up.

Comment: I don't know why this got a downvote because it appears to be the correct answer (and StackExchange won't let me upvote yet). Enabling Bonjour messaging made the option re-appear under Preferences > General. Disabling Bonjour both hid the option and disabled the menubar icon. Thanks!

Comment: Weirdly that is the answer to the problem. Apple's support article about enabling the Messages menu bar icon does not mention the requirement for enabling Bonjour. I had disabled Bonjour Messaging since I never use it, and I consider any unused network service to be a potential security problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the page You linked (works for Yosemite as well):

**Messages (Mavericks): Add Messages to the menu bar**

1. Choose Messages > Preferences, then click General.
2. Select “Show status in menu bar.” The Messages status menu appears in the menu bar as [image]
3. Click the Messages icon in the menu bar, then choose an option from the menu:

   - To set the status of all your active accounts, choose a status from the menu.
   - To send a message to an available buddy using an active account, choose a buddy from the menu.
   - To show available Bonjour buddies in the menu, choose Display Bonjour Buddies.

Comment: So then perhaps my installation is broken because I don't see that under General (I have in previous versions).

http://cl.ly/YzU9

Comment: Unfortunately I have polish version of OS X, so it might not be very helpful to paste the screenshot here. I have Yosemite and it's 4th checkbox from the bottom in General tab...

Comment: Hm, I see that others might have the same preferences panel as You: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/customize-messages-font-yosemite/ . That's strange. What Messages version You have? Mine is: 8.0 (4725) and additionaly I have Audio/Video tab in preferences.

Comment: What version of Adium.app are you running?