# Is it possible to display unread iMessage count in the menu bar on macOS 11+

Tags: macos, messages, big-sur, menu-bar

I'm aware that this [used to be possible](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162193/menubar-for-messages-in-yosemite/162195#162195) at one point or another, but I'm trying to find a solution specifically for Big Sur and up. I've recently decided to automatically hide my dock which unfortunately leads to forgetting that I've received text messages until hours later unless I open and respond to them immediately.

Is it possible, either within the system or through third-party software, to add an icon to the menu bar that indicates that there are unread messages in the stock Messages.app?

Comment: What I do is to set the `Messages` *Notification* style to *Alerts*. That way the Notfications do not disappear until I dismiss it. (Ofcourse, this is productive only if you don't receive a lot of messages or else you'll spend a lot of time clocking and dismissing each message!)